# Windows 10 right click menu's empty

Tags: windows, windows-10

After a Windows 10 update, all my right click menu's are empty.

**RMB menu of the desktop**

[image: RMB Desktop]

**RMB menu of a file**

[image: RMB File]

**RMB menu of taskbar**

[image: RMB Taskbar]

## How can I solve this?

Comment: Restart the PC and see if the problem is still present. Long thread here with many pages to read for possible solutions....http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/right-click-menu-context-menu-contains-blank-lines/b5191eae-c7f6-4813-afa7-7bf4645a5547?auth=1